# Lubuntu xbindkeys -k won't detect super + space but detects control + super + space

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, xbindkeys

I'm trying to setup a dmenu shortcut using xbindkeys with the <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> keys. When using `xbindkeys -k`, this is what I get:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

```
"(Scheme function)"
m:0x44 + c:65
Control+Mod4 + space
```

<kbd>super</kbd> alone

```
"(Scheme function)"
m:0x40 + c:133
Mod4 + Super_L
```

If I try <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, I get no response back. Anyone knows what's going on?